# Calculate mean median first third quartile from dataframe with distribution in with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, statistics, distribution

I have an aggregate level dataframe as follow:

```
errors | class | num_students
  1    | A     | 5
  2    | A     | 8
  3    | A     | 2
...
  10   | A     | 1
  1    | B     | 9
  2    | B     | 12
  3    | B     | 5
  10   | B     | 2
...
```

The original data was at student ID level so in this dataframe, distribution of errors for each class is calculated. I want to get summary statistics per class from my dataframe that looks like below:

```
Class   | average error  | median error  | Q1 error  | Q3 error
    A   |       2.1      |   2           |  1        |  3
    B   |       3.4      |   3           |  2        |  5
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It's much easier to do this with the student-level data. Is there a reason you must group it by class first?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I don't have access to the raw (student-level) data

Comment: Easiest code is `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['num_students'])].groupby('class').agg(['mean', 'med'])`.